# What is the difference between function and Function

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

What is the difference between `function` and `Function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this tutorial

```
Defining functions
The Function constructor
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 11):

`function` is a language keyword used to define functions.

`Function` is the builtin prototype object that represents all functions.

Comment: this should be the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

See the following tutorial to get the detail information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Function constructor, function means method